# Loop through pins on a Microcontroller in C where the Duty Cycle changes every hour

Tags: c, arduino

I have a Real time clock that is keeping time, and I want to change the 10 PWM outputs every hour by an increment. The idea is to stagger the PWM outputs, meaning pin 1 will be 0%, pin 2 is 25% and pin 10 is 100%. I'm trying to loop through the pins on the micro and change the duty cycle so that after one hour, pin 1 = 100% and pin 2 = 0% and pin 3 = 25% and pin 4 = 35%.

I seem to keep messing up the logic so that pins 1-10 all end up with the same duty cycle, or pin 1-10 end up with incremented duty cycles but cannot get the every hour to increment by some value. Any help would be fantastic :)

The code I'm using,

```
    int dutyPWM[10] = {0,26,52,78,104,130,156,182,208,214};
    if(Hour > 1+hour)
    {
         for(int pinnumber = 1; pinnumber < 11; pinnumber++)
          {
           for(int n=0, n <= 10; n++)
            {
             PWM_Write(pinnumber, n);
            }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I understand, every hour you want to change 10 PWM outputs. So there are too many nested loops. And your code is not complete, so it's rather guessing by the readers or a "please write that code for me" from you ?

Comment: Try to debug it with some `Serial.println` statements to see what is going on.

Comment: I added Serial.print(pinnumber, DEC); Serial.print(duty[n]); I made the duty[10] = [0,24,55,65,85,95,110,135,145,215]

Comment: First thing: is `Hour` the same variable as `hour` and it's just a typo, or you have two variables with names different only by a letter case? If the latter is true, it is a very, very bad practice to have names like that. You don't use `dutyPWM` anywhere, so what is it for? And 100% duty would be 255 not 214.

Comment: Ended up getting figuring it out, you are right what is above is pseudo code, my issues was not with syntax but logic. Had too many loops and didn't increment in the proper location. Once i went through a few interactions I got to my answer. Thank you for your feedback though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a global variable  `currentIdxStart`  and I'm using a RTC clock to keep trac of time.

```
int sizeOfArr = 10;
  int dutyPWM[sizeOfArr] = {0, 26, 52, 78, 104, 130, 156, 182, 208, 214}; 
  unsigned long nowtime = 0;
  nowtime = get_time();

if (nowtime >= num_unixtime+3600) 
 {
//setpwmfor10pumps(); 
int idx = currentIdxStart;
for (int i = 4; i <= 13; i++)
{
  analogWrite(i, dutyPWM[idx]);
  int duty = dutyPWM[idx];

  idx ++;
  if (idx >= sizeOfArr)
  {
    idx = 0;
  }
  Serial.print(i);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(duty);
  Serial.println(" ");
}

currentIdxStart++;
if (currentIdxStart >= 10)
{
  currentIdxStart = 0;
}
Serial.println(currentIdxStart); 
num_unixtime = get_time(); 
Serial.print(num_unixtime); 
Serial.println('\n');
}
```

Hope that helps anyone in the future, thanks.